# Codeigniter 3 php 7.3 mssql database (sqlsrv) error

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, codeigniter-3

I need connecting Mssql database via Codeigniter3 my PHP version is 7.3 but when I run the page I got this

```
A Database Error Occurred
SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: An unsupported attribute was designated on the PDO object.

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/system/database/drivers/pdo/pdo_driver.php

Line Number: 142
```

My application/config/database.php file like this

```
$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'   => 'sqlsrv:Server=192.168.1.4,1433;Database=DATABASENAME',
'hostname' => '192.168.1.4:1433',
'username' => 'sa',
'password' => '*****',
'database' => 'DATABASENAME',
'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => TRUE,
'db_debug' => TRUE,
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

in my php.ini file, I have

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts
```

For the solution what I tried

1 - I considered the problem  caused by driver dlls. there was the   **php_pdo_sqlsrv_73.ts.dll** but there was not   **php_pdo_sqlsrv_73.dll** (but without this dll I could work without Codeigniter my php files) have tried to find  **php_pdo_sqlsrv_73.dll** on internet to download but I could not find it.

2 - I have commented out .../database.php s hostname or database rows

is there a 3. or etc. solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have commented out

```
//'db_debug' => TRUE,
```

it solved